# Weird Coldfusion cfqueryparam

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion

```
SELECT  DISTINCT Table3.ID 
FROM    Table1 
          INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.thisID = Table2.thisID 
          INNER JOIN Table3 ON Table2.ID = Table3.ID 
WHERE ( Table1.ID IN 
         ( 
            <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" 
                value="#idlist#" list="yes">
         )
      ) 
AND   Table2.ID IN 
      (  
           <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" 
                 value="#idlist2#" list="yes">
      ) 
AND  Table3.active=1 
ORDER BY Table3.ID
```

When I run the above code it takes 11 to 15 seconds. If I remove the cfqueryparam, and just use the `idlist2` variable, the query only takes 32 milliseconds.

Is this an issue with cfqueryparam, or am I doing something incorrect?

Comment: This looks ok to me and I've never known the adding of a cfqueryparam to cause a query to take longer. Maybe try a different cfsqltype like cf_sql_numeric or cf_sql_idstamp and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: What version of ColdFusion? Are you using the SQL Server drivers that ship with that version?

Comment: Possible related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10543755/slow-query-with-cfqueryparam-searching-on-indexed-column-containing-hashes I see clearly that your data type is specified as integer but what is the table's data type set to? Have you fiddling with the value of `cfsqltype` to match?

Comment: I've tried using cf_sql_numeric, and cf_sql_idstamp.  I get the same result.  I am running cf 10 I am using whatever drivers that shipped with CF and SQL.  The data type in the database is set as int.

Comment: How many values in the two lists? Also, using a profiler - what do the two execution plans look like? ie With and without cfqueryparam?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL performance can drop precipitously with long lists in an `IN` clause. If you can reduce the length of the lists, your query performance will likely improve.

When you use `cfqueryparam`, the values are passed to SQL as a list of arguments/parameters/variables. When you do NOT use `cfqueryparam`, the list of values is hardcoded into the query string. This allows SQL's "query execution plan" to be pre-optimized for that specific list of values. It also allows the plan to be cached from one execution to the next. This can result in subsequent *identical* queries to execute very fast, like during debugging and testing.

If this is a dynamic query, if the list of values changes each time the query is run, then you want to make sure to use `cfqueryparam` so that SQL Server isn't caching the execution plan for each one-time hardcoded query.

Furthermore, `cfqueryparam` gives you a LOT of protection against [SQL Injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). From a security aspect, I recommend that *all* values being passed into a query should use `cfqueryparam`.

Finally, try running the query in SQL Server Management Studio and click the `Show Actual Execution Plan` button. It can help you determine if adding one or more indexes on your tables would help the execution time.
['Missing Index' feature of SQL Server Management Studio](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1945/missing-index-feature-of-sql-server-2008-management-studio/)

Comment: *isn't caching the execution plan for each one-time hardcoded query* Though it is worth noting even with params, it may still generate separate execution plans whenever the *number* of params change.

Comment: @Leigh Excellent point. Passing lists into a SQL query presents a lot of performance concerns. Any time list-heavy code gets near a database, I start to wonder how it can be refactored.

Comment: I have seen a rare bug involving cfqueryparam, but that did not involve INT's. I think firing up the SQL Profiler and looking at the execution plans is probably the next logical step in figuring out the cause.